# Iterating over CompactBuffer- Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, iterator

I am new to Scala and familiar with Python. I struggle to iterate over a Iterator[String] object ( Compact Buffer). I have tried foreach method without succes.

Here is my code :

```
def CCF_Iterate(pair : (String, List[Iterable[String]]) ) = {
   
   var key = pair._1
   var values_iterate = pair._2
   var min = pair._1
   val list_values = List.empty[String]

   for (value <- values_iterate) {

       if (min > value ) {
       min = value}


    list_values:+ value
}
```

And I get this error message :

```
found :    Iterable[String]
required : String
if (min > value )
        ^
```

Could someone please help me iterating over this list ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values_iterate` is a list of `Iterable` (another list or something), so as you iterate through it, the values are `Iterable` - thus the error. You need to `.flatten` it first.

Also `list_values:+ value` doesn't really do anything: `List` is immutable, it returns you a new copy with appended value, but you discard.
Also the `if` statement in the loop is inconsequential too: you are looking for the minimal value in the loop, but never use it.

Another thing is that appending to a `List` is very inefficient (it is a linked list, so appending to it is O(n)), seeing something like this in the code is usually a red flag.

Finally, in scala we very rarely use `var`, and almost never use loops.

In general, to create a flat list of values, you just do
`val list = pair._2.flatten`.
And to find the minimum value in the list, you do `list.min`.
And if you want to bound it with the value given in the parameter, then you do `math.min(min, list.min)`